# Python returns FileNotFoundError about function being defined when creating a script using PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I created a ui using PyQT designer and converted it to .py file, then pasted code previously written as a command line script which splits .mp3 file (which adress is written into a lineEdit) into chunks (number of which is read from spinBox). When trying to run the code I get FileNotFoundError concerning lines of code that are inside def function. Shouldn't it be run only when the button is pushed? I'm sure that the code shouldn't be executed before pushing the button, ergo no error code should occur before UI is displayed and button pushed.

Error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Kacper/Desktop/Apki/AtomSplitter/untitled1.py", line 95, in <module>
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
File "C:/Users/Kacper/Desktop/Apki/AtomSplitter/untitled1.py", line 66, in setupUi
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(atomsplitter(self, self.lineEdit.text(), self.spinBox.value()))
File "C:/Users/Kacper/Desktop/Apki/AtomSplitter/untitled1.py", line 18, in atomsplitter
Zawartosc = open(AdresPliku, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

Source code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.8
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
import binascii, os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(516, 191)

        def atomsplitter(self, AdresPliku, Czesci):
            NazwaPliku = os.path.basename(AdresPliku)
            Zawartosc = open(AdresPliku, 'rb')
            Zawartosc = Zawartosc.read()
            Zawartosc = (binascii.hexlify(Zawartosc))
            PoczatekIndeks = Zawartosc.find(b"fffb")
            PoczatekIndeks = PoczatekIndeks
            Poczatek = Zawartosc[0:PoczatekIndeks]
            Koniec = Zawartosc[len(Zawartosc) - 256:]
            Klatki = Zawartosc[PoczatekIndeks:len(Zawartosc) - 256]
            Czesci = int(Czesci)
            Dlugosc = int(len(Klatki) / Czesci)
            Czesc = [0]
            Indeks = [0]
            for x in range(1, Czesci + 1):
                Indeks.append(Zawartosc.find(b"fffb", Dlugosc * x))
                Czesc.append(Klatki[Indeks[x - 1]:Indeks[x]])
                strin = Czesc[x]
                print(strin[len(strin) - 20:])
                # if x == Czesci + 1:
                #    Czesc[x] = (Klatki[Indeks[x - 1]:])
                # print("Czesc" + str(x) + " " + str(len(Czesc[x])))
                CzescZawartosc = Poczatek + Czesc[x] + Koniec
                CzescZawartosc = binascii.unhexlify(CzescZawartosc)
                CzescPlik = open(NazwaPliku[:len(NazwaPliku) - 4] + str(x) + NazwaPliku[len(NazwaPliku) - 4:], "wb")
                CzescPlik.write(CzescZawartosc)
                CzescPlik.close()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 71, 31))
        self.textBrowser.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 91, 31))
        self.textBrowser_2.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 100, 61, 31))
        self.spinBox.setProperty("value", 2)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 140, 91, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")


        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 60, 271, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(atomsplitter(self, self.lineEdit.text(), self.spinBox.value()))
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.textBrowser_2, self.spinBox)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.spinBox, self.textBrowser)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Adres pliku:</p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser_2.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Liczba części:</p></body></html>"))
        self.spinBox.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Liczba części</p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Split!"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "C:\\\\Users\\\\"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The only edits I made are the atomsplitter function, importing os and binascii, and adding a connection between button and atomsplitter function.

Sorry if something is hard to understand, English is not my first language.

Comment: no, this is not a reference to a callback, it's a direct call `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(atomsplitter(self, self.lineEdit.text(), [...]` That api just expects a reference to the callback, something like `atomsplitter`. Instead, you are calling the function directly and passing its return to the the callback registrar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you connect a signal to a function you must do it through the name and its call, that is to say, `myslot` and not `myslot()`. But you can also use the `lambda`.

Change:

```
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(atomsplitter(self, self.lineEdit.text(), self.spinBox.value()))
```

to:

```
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: atomsplitter(self, self.lineEdit.text(), self.spinBox.value()))
```

Comment: How can I pass the variables to the function then? If I wanted to do it without the `lambda`?

Comment: What parameter do you want to spend?

Comment: I'd like to use lineEdit content as AdresPliku and spinBox as Czesci in atomsplitter function.